# Kodi ssh python script *no file or directory*

Tags: python, ssh, xbmc, kodi, hyperion

Im trying to run a python script through kodi which opens a SSH connection to my remote Raspberry Pi and runs a .sh script. However it sems like Kodi cant resolve paths very well.

I have ran this same python script from termux and it runs fine. Not sure if i have to use xbmc.translatepath. Any kodi legends out there know what im doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import subprocess

subprocess.call('ssh pi@192.168.1.14 -p 22 -i /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files/.kodi/addons/script.hyperion/.ssh/id_rsa bash "/home/pi/hyperion_on.sh"', shell=True)
```

See Error Below.

```
ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script 
returned the following error<--- NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.OSError'>
Error Contents: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files/.kodi/addons/script.hyperion/hyperion_on.py", line 17, in <module>
subprocess.call('ssh pi@192.168.1.14 -p 22 -i /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.xbmc.kodi/files/.kodi/addons/script.hyperion/.ssh/id_rsa bash "/home/pi/hyperion_on.sh"', shell=True)
File "/home/jenkins/workspace/Android-ARM/tools/depends/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-    androideabi-android-21/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
File "/home/jenkins/workspace/Android-ARM/tools/depends/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-    androideabi-android-21/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
File "/home/jenkins/workspace/Android-ARM/tools/depends/xbmc-depends/arm-linux-    androideabi-android-21/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

Answer (score 0):

Termux on Android is it's own self-contained environment. The commands within it are not part of the Android core system and not in any sort of path that Kodi will know by default. If you run `which ssh` you'll see it is somewhere like `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ssh`. I'm not sure if Kodi will be able to use that, though. Check out the following, it might help:

https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/77